# What are the default permissions when creating a file with fopen() in php?

Tags: php, permissions, fopen

If a file does not exist when calling

```
fopen(<filename>, 'w');
```

what are the default permissions on the new file supposed to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on your OS, it's configuration and - depending on OS - the php [`umask`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) configuration.