# PHP5 / CentOS - Automatically Give File Permissions To Fwrite Created File?

Tags: php, permissions, centos, centos6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the default permissions when creating a file with fopen() in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195533/what-are-the-default-permissions-when-creating-a-file-with-fopen-in-php)

I have PHP5 set up on my CentOS 6 VPS, I was running into some issues where I needed to grant 777 access to my scripts with Fwrite in them, the 777 change fixed when editing the files, but when I try to create a new file, example:

```
$fopen = fopen("../pages/".$_GET["mp"].".php", "w");
fwrite($fopen, $_POST["content"]);
fclose($fopen);
```

It won't create the page. This usage used to be fine on my traditional Hostgator hosting, but now on my VPS, the permissions are being denied somewhere to allow the creation of the page, even though I gave the script creating the file 777.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to allow user to write directly into `.php` files?? Especially if you let the user decide to which file to write with a get param.

Comment: @PeeHaa Its to create different pages from a back end CMS that are included using vanity URL's. Its harmless.

Comment: Wut? Why can't you just load the pages from the database? Also why do you need the permissions to be set to `777` a.k.a. free for all.

Comment: @PeeHaa Doesn't just fwriting into a /pages folder with a about.php file where I can just go to domain.com/about and it includes the file easier? I'm looking out for the user, what if they want to hard code some stuff into that page? Planting all that into a database is an option, but in my mind I'm only creating a brick wall for people trying to edit their pages, and only allowing easy to edit PHP for example in the  header or footer file.

Comment: In my experience: if people edit php they will edit the php file. If they don't know how to do that they will only break it or worse introduce vulnerabilities and should be kept as far away from php code as possible. My $0.02.

Comment: @PeeHaa Understandable. But the CMS I'm creating aims towards a different crowd. It directly aims at the idea of management, and doesn't dumb anything down to try to protect users (to an extent of course you know what I mean :P)

Comment: @NullPointer Eh, I am using PDO? Where did you assume I was using basic mysql functions?...

Comment: Which part of [What are the default permissions when creating a file with fopen() in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7195533/367456) has left open any more questions? ;)

Comment: @hakre That's right. Change the subject! I see your game. lol.