# Retrieving umask OR default permissions for file creation in PHP

Tags: php, linux, permissions, umask

If, [as answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195533/what-are-the-default-permissions-when-creating-a-file-with-fopen-in-php), when using fopen() to write a non-existing file, without specifying its permissions, default OS permissions/umask are used to determine the new file's permissions... is it possible to retrieve such default permissions via PHP ?

If PHP is running as an Apache submodule, will using for example `umask(null)` give me the umask for the Apache user in that system ?

Thank you

Comment: `umask() sets PHP's umask to mask & 0777 and returns the old umask. When PHP is being used as a server module, the umask is restored when each request is finished.` Quoted from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php